# How to Migrate data from EE 2.4.5-p1 To CE 2.4.6

Tags: migration, magento-community, magento2.4.5p1, magento2.4.6, database-export

I installed magento CE 2.4.6 in our local server and i have another database which is on magento EE 2.4.5-p1 and now i want to migrate all data from EE 2.4.5 p-1 to CE 2.4.6.